# pip command not found on RHEL5

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install AWS CLI using PIP.

```
pip --help
```

command  initially showed pip command not found.

so I followed  the guidelines to install pip by using

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py
```

It showed something like this

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /rhel5pdi/apollo/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-i686/Python27/Python27-2009.0-0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But If I use pip --help command it again shows the same error

```
pip not found
```

I searched a lot but didn't find any helpful information.

I am installing it on VMBox RHEL5.

Comment: does `python -m pip --help` work?

Comment: yaa It works..  what is difference between two commands?

Comment: `python -m pip` uses the python binary to invoke pip. It works, even if the pip script is not in your `PATH`. See the answer from @Henrik for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little UNIX 101 on a Thursday. The location of the `pip` executable is probably not in your `PATH` environment variable. If you want to run `pip` directly from your command line, you can do one of two things:

1. adding the location of `pip` to `PATH`; or
2. symlinking `pip` to some location already on you `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`.

Option 2 is probably the easiest and doesn't clutter up your `PATH`. Just create a symlink (using `sudo` if necessary):

```
ln -s /rhel5pdi/apollo/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-i686/Python27/Python27-2009.0-0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
```

However, as `pip` is installed as a Python module, you can just use module option `-m` to the interpreter:

```
python -m pip
```

You can also add an alias for this command to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias pip="python -m pip"
```

This will allow `pip` to be invoked directly from the command line.

Comment: You may want to add `python -m pip` as a third solution. I like that better than fiddling with the `PATH` variable.

Comment: symlinking didn't help.

Comment: Then `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your `PATH` variable. You can view the content of the path variable with `echo $PATH`.

Comment: yaa.. by the way I am able to install awscli using python -m pip install awscli..